# Where shall I put a DLL generated in another project from the same solution -I am using Visual Basic Visual Studio 2017-?

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

I have created a C++ DLL in Visual Studio 2017 using the following sources:

**Header: stdfax.h**

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files
#include <windows.h>



// reference additional headers your program requires here
```

**Header: targetver.h**

```
#pragma once

// Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.

// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform, include WinSDKVer.h and
// set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

**Source: stdafx.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

**Source: dll.cpp**

```
// dll.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
```

**Source: dllmain.cpp**

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**Source: Source.cpp** <- this is where I intend to add my source file

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define EXPORTING_DLL

int HelloWorld(int A) {
    return (2 * A);
}
```

**Definition: Source.def** <- Intentend to be able to consume this DLL from VB .NET

```
LIBRARY dll

DESCRIPTION 'A C++ dll tat can be called from VB'

EXPORTS
    HelloWorld
```

Now I try to consume this DLL using a VB.NET project in the same solution:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    <DllImport("dll.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Private Shared Function HelloWorld(ByVal x As Int64) As Int64
    End Function

    Private Declare Function HelloWorld Lib "dll.dll" (int) As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim j

        j = HelloWorld(CInt(TextBox1.Text))
        TextBox2.Text = j

    End Sub
End Class
```

But I get:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'dll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'
```

---

**EDIT:** Following Vincent's comment about the possibility of this being a duplicate of [Trouble adding my Visual-C++ DLL to my VB.NET windows forms GUI app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227550) I have checked that link and it does effectively tells how to add a DLL to a VB project. In that sense it is a duplicate, however, I have fixed that I find now the following error while trying to access the DLL:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)'
```

I have also, following the side comment, modified my source file containing the function that needs to be exported to:

**Source: Source.cpp** <- this is where I intend to add my source file

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define EXPORTING_DLL

extern "C" int HelloWorld(int A) {
    return (2 * A);
}
```

I think that fixing that last issue, the question could be useful to others as it is a simple but documented "HelloWorld" example on how to build a DLL in C++ and consume it in VB.NET.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble adding my Visual-C++ DLL to my VB.NET windows forms GUI app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227550/trouble-adding-my-visual-c-dll-to-my-vb-net-windows-forms-gui-app)

Comment: Note: You also need to wrap your function in an `extern "C" { }` block, otherwise you won't be able to P/Invoke it from .NET due to that C++ mangles its function names.

Comment: @visual-vincent the post you mention effectively guides you on how to add the DLL to your VB project. However I still find another issue (see edit)

Comment: A `BadImageFormatException` is thrown when you try to load a DLL of a different bitness than that of the current process. A 32-bit process cannot load 64-bit code, likewise a 64-bit process cannot load 32-bit code. You need to compile your DLL to the same bitness as your VB.NET application. If your app is targeting `AnyCPU` you must recompile it as either 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. How can I check that I am effectively using 64 bits in both cases? At least on the Debug dropbox I have selected always x64

Comment: You can find it in the C++ project settings. Right-click your project and press **Properties**, then you should find the target platform in a dropdown at the top - it should be set to `Win32`. You need to use that dropdown to create a new configuration for x64.

Comment: Thank you very much, changing the Target platform works. I can now invoke my DLL test from the VB.NET project.

Comment: Glad I could help!